Generating random prime numbers using the $6x\pm 1$ identity
In order to generate a prime number less than $N$, the current recommendation is to generate K random bits, such that $K$-bits will result in a value close to $N$ but no larger, ensure that at the very least the LSB is high. Then perform primality testing. rinse and repeat until a likely prime is found.

My question:
Given all prime numbers excluding 2 and 3 are of the form either $6x+1$ or $6x-1$, from an efficiency
point of view (aka reducing the expected number of generate-verify iterations), would it be better to generate the initial test value in the form of $6x\pm1$? - and if so how does one go about computing the new expected value for the number of iterations?

This is true. Industrial-strength prime generators (of which I have written a few) use many such filters to weed out obvious composite numbers at the random-number stage.

Of course not all prime numbers are $6x+1$ or $6x-1$, because $2$ and $3$ are not.  If you really want a randomly chosen prime $\le N$ with equal probabilities, you can't exclude $2$ and $3$ from consideration.

The random numbers not of the form $6\pm 1$ will be eliminated when dividing by $2$ or $3$, which are the first divisions to try if your method for primality testing is trial division, so it really depends on whether it's faster to calculate $6x+1$ and/or $6x-1$  then to divide by $2$ (computers are really fast at that) and $3$. If you use a more sophisticated algorithm for primality testing I refer to @TonyK's comment.

@RobertIsrael -- $2$ and $3$ are sub-primes to be checked first, but the big rest is $6x\pm 1$ me think.

@RobertIsrael you're absolutely right, I had forgot to mention the 2/3 primes are not included, I'll update the question accordingly.

Let $r$ be a random number with $K-1$ bits (so $0 \le r \le 2^{K-1} - 1)$ and $s$ = either $(-1)^b$ where $b$ is a 1-bit random number.
Let $q = 6r + s$ be a potentially prime number.  Then $-1 \le q \le 3\times2^{K} - 5$.
Of the $2^K$ possible values for $q$, there are $\pi(3\times2^{K} - 5) - 2$ primes, where $\pi$ denotes the prime-counting function.  (We subtract 2 because this algorithm will have $q \not\in \{2, 3\}$ despite those numbers being prime.)  Thus, assuming a uniform random number generator, the probability of generating a prime in any attempt is $\frac{\pi(3\times2^{K} - 5) - 2}{2^K}$.
Recall that the expected number of Bernoulli trials if each trial has probability $p$ of success is $\frac{1}{p}$.  So the expected value for the number of iterations is:
$$\frac{2^K}{\pi(3\times2^{K} - 5) - 2} \approx \frac{K\ln(2) + \ln(3)}{3}$$
For comparison, using a $K+1$ bit odd number with the last bit set to $1$ has an expected iteration count of:
$$\frac{2^K}{\pi(2^{K+1} - 1) - 1} \approx \frac{K\ln(2) + \ln(2)}{2}$$
So using the $6x\pm 1$ form requires 1/3 fewer iterations compared to the $2x+1$ form.

When sieving the $6x\pm 1$ form is also called a $2\cdot 3$-wheel. When using a $2\cdot 3\cdot 5$-wheel there are within $30$ numbers just $8$ possible canditates that could be prime. Larger wheels are not worth the effort.

@Dan this is exactly what I was looking for +1

Related is the problem of identifying whether a collection of bits has the proper form $6k\pm1$.
Clearly the units bit must be $1$ since the number must be odd. Now to check the residue modulo $3$, don't divide. Instead, add up two-bit blocks starting from the $2^0$ and $2^1$ bits and appending a leading zero if needed to complete a pair. Given the sum, repeat this two-bit addition to get a smaller sum, and iterate until only $01,10,$ or $11$ (base two) remains. (You won't get $00$ with a positive input.) The result then matches the residue of the original number $\bmod 3$, so you admit any odd candidate for which the two-bit root isn't $11$.
